# cytoscape.js accessing object

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I build a cytoscape object in a div and set all parameters required what is working just fine! On the "tap" event I add a class to the node just like this:

```
ready: function(){
   window.cy = this;
   cy.elements().unselectify();
   cy.on('tap', 'node', function(e){
   var node = e.cyTarget; 
   node.addClass('test');
```

What I want is to select nodes with this class but from outside the ready code, when clicking on a button of the web page. There is any way to do so ?

thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to your `cy` object, you can use `cy.$()` with any of the [available selectors](http://js.cytoscape.org/#selectors).  The ready event is to know when your graph has loaded and finished the initial layout.